# Over-specified linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix $A $ with RREF consisting of three of the 4, 4- dimensional standard vectors:

$[\mathbb {e_1}, \mathbb {e_2}, \mathbb {e_3} ] $

Since the rank is 3 the matrix has one solution for each 3 dimensional vector $x$ for $Ax=b $, however the system is over-specified since one row is all 0's.

Can someone why having no zero row  is not a requirement for linear independence of columns and,equally, $Ax=0$ or $Ax=b$ having one solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{A}$ having no nonzero row is *not* a requirement for linear independence of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$. However, to guarantee that a system $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ *has* a solution, showing that $\mathbf{A}$ has full rank is not enough (It would be enough only if $\mathbf{A}$ was square). The full rank of $\mathbf{A}$ guarantees that *if* there is a solution, then that solution is unique.

In order to guarantee that a solution exists in the first place, however, we also need to make sure that $\mathbf{b}$ lies in the range of $\mathbf{A}$.
How about the following example?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In the special case where $\mathbf{b}$ is the zero vector, note that the system always has at least one solution $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.
If $\mathbf{A}$ has full rank, then $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ is also the unique solution of the linear system.

Comment: Ah, yes true let me rephrase that my book said that it says the matrix must be linearly independent. This means that that matrix with $b$ being the zero column must have one solution right? But it doesn't here , yet the columns are linearly independent

Comment: It is unique. Give me two solutions that you found.

Comment: Oh I thought if you augmented any matrix A with any b and received the zero row it meant infinite solutions. In this case if u augmented A with the zero column you would have to get the zero row or there would be no solution, thus I assumed there were infinite solutions. Yet I see a zero row producing infinite solutions doesn't make sense now. Is there any situation in which a zero row in an augmented matrix for a system produces infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Think of the following: an $\mathbf{x}$ that solves the system must satisfy **all** equations. Every equation that you add can only *restrict* the number of solutions; it cannot produce more. So it might be the case that $\mathbf{0}\mathbf{x} = 0$ by itself has infinitely many solutions. But if an $\mathbf{x}$ does not satisfy the remaining equations, introducing the constraint $\mathbf{0}\mathbf{x} = 0$ will not magically make it satisfy the other equations! (It can only make things worse - make the system infeasible - if $\mathbf{0}\mathbf{x} = c$ and $c \neq 0$.)

Comment: Ah that's make sense now. I believe my confusion was with the fact that this system had 3 variables and 4 equations and having a zero row just means there was an extra uneeded equation that was a combination of the others. I was comparing this to a system with an augmented matrix such as 4×5 with 4 variables and 4 equations producing a zero row... that has infinite solutions. In addition i understand now that overspecified is not synonomous with infinite solutions. Thank you.